# How to fix Firebase Analytics Plugin install error

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics

I am trying to install firebase analytics plugin in my ionic project using

```
sudo ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics
```

But i get this as my error and the plugin isnt installed. I have tried pod install and pod update but it still gives the same error

```
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics
Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics" for ios
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics': undefined
CordovaError: Promise rejected with non-error: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/rbconfig.rb:215: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/villifixinc/Documents/TravelApp in PATH, mode 040777\n/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in `help!\': \u001b[31m[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root.\u001b[39m (CLAide::Help)\n\n\u001b[4mUsage:\u001b[24m\n\n    $ \u001b[32mpod\u001b[39m \u001b[32mCOMMAND\u001b[39m\n\n      CocoaPods, the Cocoa library package manager.\n\n\u001b[4mCommands:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[32m+ cache\u001b[39m      Manipulate the CocoaPods cache\n    \u001b[32m+ env\u001b[39m        Display pod environment\n    \u001b[32m+ init\u001b[39m       Generate a Podfile for the current directory\n    \u001b[32m+ install\u001b[39m    Install project dependencies according to versions from a\n                 Podfile.lock\n    \u001b[32m+ ipc\u001b[39m        Inter-process communication\n    \u001b[32m+ lib\u001b[39m        Develop pods\n    \u001b[32m+ list\u001b[39m       List pods\n    \u001b[32m+ outdated\u001b[39m   Show outdated project dependencies\n    \u001b[32m+ repo\u001b[39m       Manage spec-repositories\n    \u001b[32m+ setup\u001b[39m      Setup the CocoaPods environment\n    \u001b[32m+ spec\u001b[39m       Manage pod specs\n    \u001b[32m+ update\u001b[39m     Update outdated project dependencies and create new Podfile.lock\n\n\u001b[4mOptions:\u001b[24m\n\n    \u001b[34m--silent\u001b[39m     Show nothing\n    \u001b[34m--version\u001b[39m    Show the version of the tool\n    \u001b[34m--verbose\u001b[39m    Show more debugging information\n    \u001b[34m--no-ansi\u001b[39m    Show output without ANSI codes\n    \u001b[34m--help\u001b[39m       Show help banner of specified command\n\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in `run\'\n\tfrom /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>\'\n\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load\'\n\tfrom /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>\'\n'
    at cli.catch.err (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova:29:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics exited with exit
        code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try installing the older version of the plugin. version 2.0.3 should fix your problem.

Comment: It installs now but when i try to run the build on my iOS device it gives an error "module Firebase not found"

Comment: Edit your plugin.xml and add  version=">=9.0.0" support. or you can downgrade to plugin version 1.1.1 both should fix your issue
<engines> 
<engine name="cordova" version=">=7.1.0"/>
 <engine name="cordova" version=">=9.0.0"/> 
<engine name="cordova-android" version=">=7.0.0"/> 
<engine name="cordova-ios" version=">=5.0.0"/> 
</engines>
please upvote if its helpful

Comment: Sorry where do i locate the plugin.xml file in ionic4. Ive searched everywhere